# Is F# List.collect same as in C# List.SelectMany?

Tags: c#, linq, f#

Are the List.collect equivalent of LINQ List.SelectMany?

```
[1;2;3;4] |> List.collect (fun x -> [x * x]) // [1;4;9;16]
```

in LINQ

```
new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
       .SelectMany(x => new List<int>() { x * x }); // 1;4;9;16
```

**Edited:**

More appropriate example

```
let list1 = [1;2;3;4]
let list2 = [2;4;6]

// [2; 4; 6; 4; 8; 12; 6; 12; 18; 8; 16; 24]
list1 |> List.collect (fun a -> list2 |> List.map (fun b -> a * b))
```

...

```
var list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var list2 = new List<int>() { 2, 4, 6 }

// 2,4,6,4,8,12,6,12,18,8,16,24
list1.SelectMany(a => list2.Select(b => a * b));
```

Comment: Given the description at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.collect%5B't%2C'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D, it certainly looks like that to me.

Comment: (Although your example doesn't work, in that you seem to have switched from doubling to squaring half way through...)

Comment: @Jon Skeet I changed it

Comment: (It would be clearer if you used a mapping function that returned multiple elements, admittedly...)

Comment: since when is `1 * 1 = 2`?

Comment: @MatthewWhited I fixed it

Comment: Just FYI; in other languages `collect`/`SelectMany` is known as `flatMap` (scala, java, kotlin etc). Sometimes it's known as `bind` or `>>=`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

More or less.  The direct F# equivalent to `SelectMany` would be `Seq.collect` which has the signature:

```
Seq.collect : ('T -> 'Collection) -> seq<'T> -> seq<'U> (requires 'Collection :> seq<'U>)
```

`seq<'T>` is just a type alias for `IEnumerable<T>`.

F# `list` is a concrete collection (an immutable list) and consequently `List.collect` is evaluated strictly.

Note also that F# `list` and the .NET `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` types are not equivalent.  `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` is a mutable collection and is normally referred to via its type alias `ResizeArray<'T>` in F#.

Answer (score 8):

They behave the same however `Enumerable.SelectMany` returns a lazy sequence (`IEnumerable<T>`) while `List.collect` returns a list which is created strictly. Also be aware that F# lists are persistent linked lists while C# lists are backed by an array.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to mention that nothing will stop you from using the LINQ extension methods directly in F#:

```
open System.Linq
open System.Collections.Generic
open System

let xs = seq [seq [1;2;3];  seq [4;5;6]] 
xs.SelectMany(fun x -> x ).Select(fun x -> x * x)
// val it: IEnumerable<int> = seq [1; 4; 9; 16; ...]
```

And for a more idiomatic solution for your specific example in F# 4.1 (though it only works on two lists):

```
let list1 = [1;2;3;4]
let list2 = [2;4;6]
(list1,list2) ||> List.allPairs |> List.map (fun (a,b) -> a * b)
//val it : int list = [2; 4; 6; 4; 8; 12; 6; 12; 18; 8; 16; 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

List.map is function that you are looking.

Comment: Not for an equivalent to `SelectMany` - `List.map` is equivalent to `Select`, isn't it?